# python variable scope

Tags: python

I have started to learn about python and is currently reading through a script written by someone else. I noticed that globals are scattered throughout the script (and I don't like it).. Besides that, I also noticed that when I have code like this

```
def some_function():
    foo.some_method()
    # some other code

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    foo = Some_Object()

    some_function()
```

even though I don't pass in foo into some_function(), but some_function is still able to manipulate foo (??!). I don't quite like this although it is somewhat similar to Javascript closure (?). I would like to know whether it is possible to stop some_function() from accessing foo if foo is not passed in as a function argument? Or this is the preferred way in python??! (I'm using python 2.5 under ubuntu hardy at the moment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That script has really serious issues with style and organization -- for example, if somebody imports it they have to somehow divine the fact that they have to set `thescript.foo` to an instance of `Some_Object` before calling `some_function`... yeurgh!-)

It's unfortunate that you're having to learn Python from a badly written script, but I'm not sure I understand your question. Variable scope in Python is locals (including arguments), nonlocals (i.e., locals of surrounding functions, for nested functions), globals, builtins.

Is what you want to stop access to globals?  `some_function.func_globals` is read-only, but you could make a new function with empty globals:

```
import new
f=new.function(some_function.func_code, {})
```

now calling `f()` will given an exception `NameError: global name 'foo' is not defined`. You could set this back in the module with the name `some_function`, or even do it systematically via a decorator, e.g.:

```
def noglobal(f):
    return new.function(f.func_code, {})
...
@noglobal
def some_function(): ...
```

this will guarantee the exception happens whenever `some_function` is called. I'm not clear on what benefit you expect to derive from that, though. Maybe you can clarify...?

Comment: just finished removing the globals, I'm currently looking at nonlocals (locals of surrounding functions - for nested functions)

I want to reduce the amount of non-local used probably because of a habit I brought from coding in PHP - if a variable is not passed into a function, then the variable doesn't exist in the function (which IMO, it is easier to debug if bad things happen)

Comment: @Jeffrey, yes wrt globals, but nonlocals, especially if a function is just accessing them and NOT reassigning them (the latter being really an option only in 2.6 and later with the `nonlocal` keyword), are not really a problem -- and I speak on the basis of decades of hard-won experience;-).

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only way to stop `some_function` from accessing `foo` is to eliminate the `foo` variable from `some_function`'s scope, possibly like:

```
tmp = foo
del foo
some_function()
foo = tmp
```

Of course, this will crash your (current) code since `foo` doesn't exist in the scope of `some_function` anymore.

In Python, variables are searched locally, then up in scope until globally, and finally built-ins are searched.

Another option *could* be:

```
with some_object as foo:
    some_function()
```

But then, you'll have to at least declare `some_object.__exit__`, maybe `some_object.__enter__` as well.  The end result is that you control which `foo` is in the scope of `some_function`.

More explanation on the "with" statement [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm).

Comment: Replacing globals with passed argument values is always challenging.  It seems like there's always one more silly reference to the global floating around.  Therefore, when fixing this global mess, rename your legacy global variables as you rewrite your functions to take arguments instead of globals.  Then things break for the right reason.

Answer (score 1):

In python, something like `foo` is not a value, it's a *name*.  When you try to access it, python tries to find the value associated with it (like dereferencing a pointer).  It does this by first looking in the local scope (the function), then working its way outwards until it reaches the module scope (i.e. global), and finally builtins, until it finds something matching the name.

That makes something like this work:

```
def foo():
    bar()

def bar():
    pass
```

Despite the fact that `bar` doesn't exist when you defined `foo`, the function will work because you later defined `bar` in a scope that encloses `foo`.

Exactly the same thing is going on in the code you post, it's just that `foo` is the output of `Some_Object()`, not a function definition.

As Alex said, the fact that you *can* write code like that does not mean that you *should*.